Access Violation Exception when calling ADODB connection get_state()
My C# app occurred 'Access Violation Exception' when calling ADODB connection 'get_state()'.
Not always, just once.
What does this app do is, Delete all data from a table & Insert data into the same table.
Keep running the task in WhileLoop, waiting 10 sec after each task.
It's running in a single task.
Delete & Insert are in same transaction because we need to Delete old data only when new data Insert will be done successfully.
Built option: 'AnyPCU'.
Database: SQLserver Express 2014.
ADODB connection variable is not static.

Exception code: 0xc0000005
Offset: 0x000b55bc
Module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\sqloledb.dll

StackTrace:
System.AccessViolationException
Place: ADODB.ConnectionClass.get_State()

This app has to run continuously so as an workaround I am planning to add a code to catch the Access Violation Exception so the app won't crash.
I also will change ADODB connection variable to 'static' to make the usage serially.
But I need to find why it's happening to decide if this workaround is fine or not.

you don't show any code, but if I had to guess (and emphasis: this is pure speculation, but let's call it "speculation based on experience"): is it possible that you have a connection instance that is stored between uses (in a field somewhere, perhaps) and is being used concurrently by two separate threads? (either explicit threads, or via Task/async/some-other-callback). ADO.NET objects are not designed to be thread-safe, and the moment you have concurrent access, bad things happen very quickly.

"I also will change ADODB connection variable to 'static' to make the usage serially." - that sounds like a terrible idea, for the above reasons - it simply makes it easier to shoot your foot off; if you're trying to debug ADO.NET code (at least for weird connection shenanigans), the first thing to do is to reduce connection reuse - even just using (var conn = new WhateverConnection(...)) {...} for every single data access (as a debug mechanism; I'm not saying you can never reuse connections - just: this is useful to rule out accidental concurrent use)
